# RAM compatibility between MacBook Pros

Tags: memory, compatibility

I was hoping someone could help me determine if the original RAM from my mid-2012 13" MacBook Pro could be put into my mid-2009 13" MacBook Pro?

here are the specs of the original RAM

- 2x 2GB RAM  4GB PC3-12800 SODIMM

  - DDR3 SDRAM
  - 204-pin
  - PC3-10600
  - 1.5V
  - 1333 MT/s

Comment: There's a great free app on the Mac App Store called EveryMac  that is great for looking up specs about Apple products, even down to the RAM specs for each individual model.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the specs for the mid 2009 13" MacBook Pro:

- Double Data Rate Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Module (DDR3) format
- 30mm (1.18 inch)
- 2 GB or 4 GB
- 204-pin
- PC3-8500 DDR3 1066 MHz type RAM

And the mid 2012 13" MacBook Pro:

- Double Data Rate Small Outline Dual Inline Memory Module (DDR3) format
- 67.6mm x 30mm (1.18 inch)
- 2 GB or 4 GB
- 204-pin
- PC3-12800 DDR3 1600 MHz type RAM

It'll work, it's slightly faster than the RAM it came with.

Comment: The newer RAM is faster as a specification however that doesn't mean it will run at the faster speed in the older computer if its FSB can't handle the increased speed specification.

Comment: Correct, but it'll work even if the FSB doesn't support the full speed. It'll just perform at the max speed supported.

Comment: Yes it will work however I made that statement in response to you saying "_It'll work, it's slightly faster than the RAM it came with._" because as written it might lead one to think it will be as fast in the old system. The FSB is 1066 MHz on the old system so the 1600 MHz RAM will only run at 1066 MHz on the old system.